# How to declare a class object in Kotlin

Tags: class, object, kotlin

I am implementing a user registration system in my app and want to save the user data step by step in a class named 'UserProfile'.

I managed to do create a class and declare its object but  the app gets not responding when i click the button. My code is showing no errors. I guess i am not able to declare the object of the class properly.

```
class RegisterActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register)

        class UserProfile {
            private lateinit var username: String
            private lateinit var mobile: String
            private lateinit var email: String
            private lateinit var address1: String
            private lateinit var address2: String
            private lateinit var gender: String
            fun add(data:String,i:Int){
                when (i){
                    1 -> username = data
                    2 -> mobile = data
                    3 -> email = data
                    4 -> address1 = data
                    5 -> address2 = data
                    6 -> gender = data
                }
            }
        }
        var registrationStep= 1
        lateinit var user: UserProfile
        val inputBox = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)
        val textBox = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
        val data = inputBox.text.toString()
        val nextBTN = findViewById<Button>(R.id.NextBtn)
        nextBTN.setOnClickListener {
            println("Clicked Listener2")
            user.add(data,registrationStep)

            when (registrationStep){
                1 ->  textBox.text = getString(R.string.register1)
                2 ->  textBox.text = getString(R.string.register2)
                3 ->  textBox.text = getString(R.string.register3)
                4 ->  textBox.text = getString(R.string.register4)
                5 ->  textBox.text = getString(R.string.register5)
                6 ->  textBox.text = getString(R.string.register6)
            }
            registrationStep += 1
        } 
   }
}
```

I expect the 'EditText' value to be saved in the class and text of 'TextView' to be changed when the 'Button' button is pressed. But instead of that the app keeps on closing and not responding when i click the 'Button' Button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to instantiate object of your class prior use. Declaration is not equivalent. So replace

```
lateinit var user: UserProfile
```

with

```
var user: UserProfile = UserProfile()
```

Comment: The class object is declared successfully but now for some reason user.add() is not working . Please Help i am new to Kotlin